# Performance concerns when storing multiple bitmaps

Tags: android, performance, bitmap, android-view

I have created a custom `View` object which overrides the `onDraw` method to paint a fairly involved UI. I am adding 5 of these custom views onto a LinearLayout, *but only one View is visible at any one time*.

Depending on the users' actions inside my application, I am toggling the `View.Visibility` property on each so that only one is visible.

**Just for clarification, the method I'm using works for me and it seems to be fairly responsive. I'm just a little concerned how this method would affect lower-end or lower-spec devices.**

Here is a sample of my current code:

**Custom View**

```
public class MyDrawingView extends View {
  private Bitmap mViewBitmap;

  private int mWidth = 1024; // The width of the device screen
  private int mHeight = 600; // Example value, this is dynamic

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // Copy the in-memory bitmap to the canvas.
    if(mViewBitmap != null) canvas.drawBitmap(mViewBitmap, 0, 0, mCanvasPaint);
  }

  private void drawMe() {
    if(mViewBitmap == null) mViewBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWidth, mHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(mViewBitmap);
    c.drawBitmap(...);
    c.drawText(...);
    // Multiple different methods here drawing onto the canvas
    c.save();
  }
}
```

**Layout XML**

```
<LinearLayout>
  <com.company.project.ui.MyDrawingView
            android:id="@+id/myCustomView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <com.company.project.ui.MyDrawingView
            android:id="@+id/myCustomView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <com.company.project.ui.MyDrawingView
            android:id="@+id/myCustomView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <com.company.project.ui.MyDrawingView
            android:id="@+id/myCustomView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <com.company.project.ui.MyDrawingView
            android:id="@+id/myCustomView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Questions**

1. Should I be keeping these 5 separate instances of my View, with Bitmaps of size 1024x600, in memory all the time?
2. Should I merge the functionality, so that I need only add one View to my layout XML then re-generate a Bitmap each time a View needs to be updated?
3. Which option is better for performance, bearing in mind that redrawing my Bitmap may take some time due to its complexity?

**Documentation**

I have already read the Android documentation on [Managing Bitmap Memory](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html), however I feel I have implemented the points outlined already in my custom View and I don't think it quite covers my scenario.

Comment: Your biggest problem with low-end devices is going to be heap size. Your bitmaps take up `1024*600*4*5=12MB` of memory by themselves(ARGB_8888). In devices with a 16MB heap, that's quite a big chunk. That's assuming the images are only 1024x600, also. If your values are dynamic, they may not fit in the heap at all.

Comment: @Geobits Exactly what I was worried about. So how does one avoid this while keeping performance smooth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I took on-board Geobits' comments on heap size and came up with a solution to the issue:

1. Go with one View, which will dynamically draw data onto a single *internal* `Bitmap` as required
2. Change the bitmap type to `RGB_565` in order to make the bitmap slightly smaller
3. Delete/recycle the bitmap where possible

After the above, I managed to reduce the required RAM to 25Mb for the entire application which I'm more than happy with.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why are you putting a `LinearLayout` with views inside that have the size of device and then hiding accordingly. You'll be better off using a [`ViewFlipper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) or even better a [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html).

The best one would be the ViewPager since then you can deallocate the bitmaps from memory when not visible.

Also, if you are loading an image from the internet or the SD card you can use [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), which simplifies caching and memory management for you. no need to reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: The `LinearLayout` wrapper is just an example. In reality, the layout XML is much more complicated, however it's just this section of the View I'm concerned about, and mainly about the impact of storing such large Bitmaps in memory. What benefit would `ViewFlipper` or `ViewPager` provide over my current method given that I don't require any animation or user interaction - this is all already handled within my View

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, ViewPager has the benefit of setting the offscreen page limit. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)

Comment: `ViewFlipper` will handle all the visibility stuff making your code more readable. `ViewPager` as mentioned will provide you an easier way to recycle views. But I think the most important one would be UIL since it will make loading images a very simple and safe task since it's a fairly well tested library.
"Standing on the shoulder of giants" ;)